# What model is my bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Could you please help me identify my bike? I am really struggling! I have tried to do it on my own but I need help.

I've never had a bike that's had internally-routed cables before

It says Specialised Elite on the frame but I think there are LOADS of different bikes with this name...

Is it a somewhat valuable frame?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI: Your pics are behind a warning about them being "erotic or adult imagery." I was somewhat reluctant to click through. Others may be as well. You can edit those images directly into your post on this site.

Comment: Where did you get the bike? The seller may have more information about its origins.

Comment: Imgur can be like that, they don't control what users will post so its possible for other users to see uncontrolled content.   SE uses a dedicated instance of the imgur setup for hosted photos, which is a different set of hosts to the public-facing imgur.   Upshot, uploading your photos using the "insert" button above the editor works well.   I've done this for you already.

Answer (score 3):

Looking up the SKU (9029 5303) along with the serial which starts with WSBC indicates that it is a genuine Specialized Sirrus of unknown year.

It’s not a valuable frame in any sense. it’s one of thousands of aluminium Sirrus frames that were made in that year for a likely BOM “cost” of $50 - $100. Not bad quality, just not exceptional quality. A consumer frame gets it’s value from the components that are stuck on it by the manufacturer.

You’d want to evaluate if 2 new 29”/700C wheels & tyres, a cassette, chain and chainrings (maybe a whole new crankset) plus anything else you’d want or need to replace like the seat and bottom bracket are worth the value vs a new bike.

Comment: Some information on the Sirrus I could quickly find (If you look closely, it is actually written on the top tube). It is Specialized's fitness bike offering and the most expensive (aluminium) option costs 1100€/$, the basic model goes for 540€ including disc brakes and 8-speed Shimano Acera. Yours more looks like a 2010s model, just judging by the design and rim brakes. As Warren said, fixing everything that's used, broken or missing will probably end up in the price range of a new Sirrus.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you so much for your considerate replies. @Warren Burton and DoNuT I got this Specialised Elite frame with a bunch of other frames and wheels and stuff all together as a joblot. I've got lots of wheels and spare components so I should be able to fully repair it all. jimchristie thanks for the heads up I did not realise and I could not figure out how to upload and inline an image directly into my post

Comment: It's a 2012 or 2013.